# sidekiq Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq, ruby-2.0

```
Cannot define multiple 'included' blocks for a Concern
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/concern.rb:126:in `included'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/high_voltage-2.1.0/app/controllers/concerns/high_voltage/static_page.rb:4:in `<module:StaticPage>'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/high_voltage-2.1.0/app/controllers/concerns/high_voltage/static_page.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `load'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:443:in `block in load_file'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:633:in `new_constants_in'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:442:in `load_file'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:342:in `require_or_load'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:307:in `depend_on'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `require_dependency'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:468:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `each'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:467:in `block in eager_load!'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `each'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:465:in `eager_load!'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `each'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:58:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p643/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `public_send'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/railties-4.1.9/lib/rails/railtie.rb:194:in `method_missing'
/home/andreydeineko/partner-plus/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/activesupport-4.1.9/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:241:in `boot_system'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/lib/sidekiq/cli.rb:50:in `run'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/gems/sidekiq-3.3.4/bin/sidekiq:8:in `<top (required)>'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/bin/sidekiq:23:in `load'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/bin/sidekiq:23:in `<main>'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/andreydeineko/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p643@app_name/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

It's connected to Rails itself I assume, meaning I don't have problems with concenrs as it's apparent from error trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
bundle update high_voltage
```

Comment: Well, it says it was fixed in a later version.  Try again. https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage/issues/136

Comment: ok, i was having locked high_voltage gem version (2.1.0) and current is 2.4.0. Updating to newest one solved the issue. Greatly appreciated!